# how to check if the member is joined to an specific voice channel DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to check if the member is joined to the voice channel that the bot is joined.
The whole code is working, I just want to add that line that I put in code comments.
My code:

```js
const { QueryType } = require('discord-player');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['p'],
    permissions: ['CONNECT'],
    description: 'Plays a music',
    voiceChannel: true,

    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord, profileData) {
// if the member that used the comamnd is not joined to the voicechannel that the bot is playing music on it, return;
        const player = client.player
if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send({ content: `${message.author}, Write the name of the music you want to search. <:Cross:961558777667149874>` });

        const res = await client.player.search(args.join(' '), {
            requestedBy: message.member,
            searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
        });

        if (!res || !res.tracks.length) return message.channel.send({ content: `${message.author}, No results found! <:Cross:961558777667149874>` });

        const queue = await client.player.createQueue(message.guild, {
            metadata: message.channel
        });

        try {
            if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(message.member.voice.channel)
        } catch {
            await client.player.deleteQueue(message.guild.id);
            return message.channel.send({ content: `<:Cross:961558777667149874> ${message.author}, I can't join audio channel ` });
        }

if(client.config.opt.selfDeaf === false) {
let channel = message.member.voice.channel;
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
   channelId: channel.id,
   guildId: channel.guild.id,
   adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
   selfDeaf: false
});
}

        res.playlist ? queue.addTracks(res.tracks) : queue.addTrack(res.tracks[0]);

        if (!queue.playing) await queue.play();
        

    },
};
```

I am not getting any errors.
I am using node.js v16 and discord.js v13

Comment: Are you using slash comands?

Comment: No, i'm using prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to return if the member isn't in the same voice channel as you.

```
if(message.member.voice.channelId !== message.guild.me.voice.channelId) return;
```

Then it will return if they aren't in the same channel.